# How can I add headings to my protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reports

Tags: protractor, jasmine

I am sharing my spec file, the generated report contains only 'through Gmail Account' text but I want to add 'Password pop up' text and many other headings also. I tried by adding one more 'it' block contains password code but my code was not working. Please help me out I want to make report shows the headings for all test cases.

My spec file is:

```
describe('Login', function () {
    afterEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;     });
    it(' through Gmail Account', function () {  
        var GM = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  
        browser.get("http://folio3.github.io/eCareVault/#");
        //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        var gmail = element(by.css('.ggl>img'));
        browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(gmail), 5000);
        gmail.click();               
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        element(by.id("Email")).click();
        element(by.id("Email")).sendKeys('tfatima5050@gmail.com');
        element(by.id("next")).click();
        element(by.id("Passwd")).click();
        element(by.id("Passwd")).sendKeys('click123');
        element(by.id("signIn")).click();
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
//Password popup
       var Password = element(by.model("anyvalue"));
       browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(Password), 10000);
       Password.sendKeys("123");
       element(by.id("submit")).click();
       element(by.css('.overview' )).click();
       element(by.css('.edit' )).click();       element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/form/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')).click().clear().sendKeys('bob');    
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely missing some test case grouping and a `beforeEach()` where you would navigate to an initial "Log In" page. You should have something along these lines:

```
describe('Login', function () {
    var GM;

    beforeEach(function () {
        GM = protractor.ExpectedConditions;;
        browser.get("http://folio3.github.io/eCareVault/#");
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;     
    });

    it('should log in through Gmail Account', function () {  
        var gmail = element(by.css('.ggl>img'));
        browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(gmail), 5000);
        gmail.click();          

        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
            element(by.id("Email")).click();
            element(by.id("Email")).sendKeys('tfatima5050@gmail.com');
            element(by.id("next")).click();
            element(by.id("Passwd")).click();
            element(by.id("Passwd")).sendKeys('click123');
            element(by.id("signIn")).click();

            browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
        });
    });

    it('should log in using password', function () { 
       var Password = element(by.model("anyvalue"));
       browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(Password), 10000);
       Password.sendKeys("123");
       element(by.id("submit")).click();
       element(by.css('.overview' )).click();
       element(by.css('.edit' )).click();       
       element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/form/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')).click().clear().sendKeys('bob');    
    }); 
});
```

You are also missing logging out (as an "after each" action?), actually testing things - making expectations using `expect()`.

Comment: its not working as I did the same thing previously by separating test cases with 'it' blocks but after login the test fails it is not entering anything on encryption pop up.

Comment: @RozmeenAli how does it fail and on which line? Thanks.

Comment: After login, it just logout from the system. The test case doesn't execute the password pop up test cases.

Comment: Message:
    Failed: Wait timed out after 100009ms
  Stack:
    Error: Wait timed out after 100009ms

Comment: @RozmeenAli ah, on this line `browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(gmail), 5000);`? Are you sure the selector is correct?

Comment: yeah the selector is correct if I remove 'it' block from password pop up than its working correctly.